# Failed to Unregister DataSource JMX MBean While Shutting Down a Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, jmx, spring-boot, spring-jmx

I have a simple Spring Boot application using org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource as dataSource bean.

The data source is exposed as MBean automatically by Spring boot.

The bean declaration:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(jdbcDriver);
    dataSource.setUsername(dbUserName);
    dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
    return dataSource;
}
```

Everything works fine . However, I see error while shutting down the application. This error only occurs when running the executable jar. When using Gradle Spring plugin (gradle bootRun), this is not shown.

```
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp2:name=dataSource,type=BasicDataSource
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.exclusiveUnregisterMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:427)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.unregisterMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:415)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.unregisterMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:546)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.close(BasicDataSource.java:1822)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.invokeCustomDestroyMethod(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:540)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:827)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:485)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:152)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:809)
```

I am wondering, 
1. How does this bean get exposed as JMX MBean?
2. How to properly unregister this MBean?

Comment: This does not seem to have anything to do with Boot. The datasource itself tries to unregister from a JMX domain and fails. How about looking that data source type documentation? Any reason why you can't use the infrastructure that boot provides by the way?

Comment: Stumbled across this as I have encountered the same issue. It is actually not an error - the log reports the condition as a warning. As to why not use the Boot data sources, I would wager a guess that the OP wants to fine-tune the connection pooling, and if you do not run in a container (which would pool for you), you do not actually get a pooled connection from Boot (SimpleDriverDataSource does not actually give you pooled connections). I'd love to know how to fix this with DBCP2, but if it is only a warning that occurs on shutdown, I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: This comes from Spring. As @Will said this is only a warning. The BasicDataSource tries to unregister but is already unregistered by Spring (destroy() in MBeanExporter). Thus it should be no problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Spring is trying to close BasicDataSource twice:

1. BasicDataSource close itself automatically when application close
2. Spring use default destroy method to close DataSource but it's already closed

To avoid this, use:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "")
public DataSource dataSource()
```

In your Java Configuration

Comment: this solved my problem , no more stack trace during server shutdown

Comment: Working perfectly, resolved the issue for me as well

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. Adding an MBean server and registering the datasource can not fix it either.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html

My conclusion is that DBCP2's BasicDataSource has a bug at unregistering itself from the MBean server.

I fixed mine by switching to mchange's c3p0:
http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/

Answer (score 1):

`BasicDataSource extends BasicDataSourceMXBean`, so it is auto registered with JMX server as MBean `[org.apache.commons.dbcp2:name=dataSource,type=BasicDataSource]`. When springboot shutdowns, MBeanExporter unregisters the MBean, then springboot tries to destroy `BasicDataSource`, and calls BasicDataSource’s method `close()`, unregisters the MBean again (BasicDataSource catches the JMException, and print this warning). It’s just a warning. If you don’t want to print it, you can disable JMX in springboot.

```
application.yml
spring:
jmx:
enabled: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. 
c3p0 works very well.

if using `spring framework` - pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
   <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
   <version>0.9.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

initially used

```
DataSource ds_unpooled = DataSources.unpooledDataSource(persistenceUrl,
            persistenceUsername,
            persistencePassword);
return DataSources.pooledDataSource(ds_unpooled);
```

but it couldn't handle the load I need to perform and switched to the following

```
ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    cpds.setDriverClass( persistenceDriver ); //loads the jdbc driver
    cpds.setJdbcUrl( persistenceUrl );
    cpds.setUser(persistenceUsername);
    cpds.setPassword(persistencePassword);
    cpds.setMinPoolSize(5);
    cpds.setMaxPoolSize(50);
    cpds.setUnreturnedConnectionTimeout(1800);
    cpds.setMaxStatements(50);
    cpds.setMaxIdleTime(21600);
    cpds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(10800);
return cpds;
```

those values are from other posts that I have gathered online.

in my experience for my specific task, running c3p0 performs faster than dbcp2 v:2.1.1 under the same environment.

hope this help a bit. 
cheers!